# codeigniter initialize variable on each model method call

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor, model

In codeigniter I want to initialize variables every time I call method of a model.
I tried using constructors but constructors are called only when your model is loaded once and after that any call to the method of loaded class/model doesn't call its constructor again.

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating models and instantiating objects like standard PHP. While not standard CodeIgniter practice, sometimes using basic PHP is the best approach.

For example, I place my `Foo` class in `models/Foo.php`:

```
class Foo {
    protected $bar;

    public function baz() {
        echo $this->bar;
    }

    public function __constuct($bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}
```

Then, I `require_once` the file and fire up a new instance whenever I need it. This gives me the flexibility to create new objects using different parameters.

If you need to have access to the global `CodeIgniter` object, you can always create a `$ci` property and assign it the value of `get_instance()` in the beginning of your constructor.

Comment: i want something related to ci not core php, anyways thanx for the efforts

Answer (score 0):

the first idea that comes to my mind is:

To send those variables as parameters to your model whenever you call that model example:

**Controller**:

```
$this->load->model('Product_mdl');
$this->product_mdl->init(10,20,30);
```

**Model (product_mdl.php)**

```
<?php
    class Product_mdl extends CI_Model
    {
     private $var1 = $var2 = $var3 = NULL;

     public function init($value1, $value2, $value3)
     {
      $this->var1 = $value1;
      $this->var2 = $value2;
      $this->var3 = $value3;
     } 

    // now you can call $this->varx in the remaining model code
    ...

    }
```

Comment: i cant pass variables every time, basically i want variables which are assigned  default value by model class and if model performs some logic than i need to update those variables and return updates values or else default values.

Comment: @KaushilRambhia are those variables constants ? or generated ?

Comment: @KaushilRambhia in that case why don't you create a table in the database and store those values in that table, read those variables from database on the methods of your model and update them if you need to do so

Comment: I have some variables which are initialized when i called constructor now there are many controllers which  are calling many methods of this model and if model logic goes right return back updated variables or send old initialized variable..also querying everytime database is not correct in my scenario.

Comment: @KaushilRambhia is there a chance you can use session ?

Comment: no man variables are like     `$response = array("status"=>true,"data_count"=>0,"data"=>$mydata)`